# Run spiders in the background every n minutes when django server is running

Tags: django, scrapy

I have a django project. Inside this project, there are some crawlers that crawl data from some websites and store it in database. With the django, these crawled data is shown.

This is the structure of project:

```
-prj
   db.sqlite3
   manage.py
   -prj
       __init__.py
       settings.py
       urls.py
       wsgi.py
   -prj_app
       __init__.py
       prj_spider.py
       admin.py
       apps.py
       models.py
       runner.py
       urls.py
       views.py
```

I want to run all spiders in the background every 5 minutes when django server is running. In the `views.py` I have import `runner.py` and in the `runner.py` all spiders start crawling.

views.py:

```
from . import runner
```

runner.py:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from .prj_spider import PrjSpider
from background_task import background

@background()
def run_spider(spider):
    def f(q):
        try:
            configure_logging()
            runner = CrawlerRunner()
            deferred = runner.crawl(spider)
            deferred.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
            reactor.run()
            q.put(None)
        except Exception as e:
            q.put(e)

    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    result = q.get()
    p.join()

    if result is not None:
        raise result

for spider in spiders:
    run_spider(DivarSpider, repeat=60)
```

When run the server, I get this error:

> TypeError: Object of type type is not JSON serializable

Also with this type of `runner.py`, I get below error:

runner.py:

```
@background()
def fetch_data():
    runner = CrawlerRunner()
    runner.crawl(PrjSpider)
    d = runner.join()
    d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run()

fetch_data(repeat=60)
```

error:

> raise error.ReactorNotRestartable() twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable

Comment: Have you ever start all spiders together before with reactor?  I mean is this error just show up? Because I try run all spiders with reactor and it doesn't go well.

Comment: @MuratDemir Yes, I can start all spiders together for 1 time in background ... But I don't know how can schedule that